# An achievement system to privileges

Tags: discussion, privileges, achievements-dialog

So I just posted one question and all of a sudden I have 3 new privileges.
I can only assume knowing more about my new privileges would enhance my experience here, but I don't exactly have the time to sort through it all and see what I can do.

What do you all think of, in addition to unlocking privileges, a system of "exercises" that demonstrates each new privilege, granting additional achievements for practicing each?

This system could also provide secondary achievements all connected to each other that we could consult to see first hand what privileges of ours we are clearly aware of and what we may not have tried out yet.

Comment: There is more information on the privilege if you go to the help pages which is where they expect people to go to learn more.

Comment: Continued use of the site, and posting things that net the EXP, are those exercises you speak of

Comment: There's already an "achievement" system for using your unlocked privileges: [Badges.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) And look: You already have [7 of them!](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3292340/mark-belain?tab=badges)

Comment: *"but I don't exactly have the time to sort through it all and see what I can do"* so you want a system created to create more work because you don't want to look through the, not all that long, privilege list (or even just the new ones you have acquired)?

Comment: I don't understand why my question deserves so much hate... I just feel it would be useful to know the difference between what I've unlocked and what I've mastered...

Comment: Voting on meta is often used just to indicate disagreement. People also feel more free to vote since it doesn't affect rep. Don't read it as "hate" just "I don't think this is needed."

Comment: Oh, I could have sworn I read somewhere that being downvoted too often will get me silenced. Helps to know that isn't the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a system of "exercises" that demonstrates each new privilege

There are some problems with this.

- It's not faster than reading the list of [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). The description of each is just one sentence
- Some privileges already have some help text/dialogs for the first time you use them
- For other privileges it doesn't make sense to have a tutorial/demo/exercise of it. For example, the ability to post more links. It doesn't make sense to have another thing explaining this because you already get an explanation from Markdown help.

If there's one in particular that needs more explanation maybe something should be added for it but there doesn't appear to be an across the board issue with explaining privileges.

Comment: The privileges list you linked is more or less what I was talking about; I guess I just didn't realize the privilege list to be so short. Having unlocked 3 in one go, I assumed I was going to have to accept a tendency for unlocking overwhelming numbers or privileges at a time.

Comment: @MarkBelain - The link to the privileges list used to be a lot more obvious before they changed the profile. The fastest way to get to it now is to click on the Badges button and go to the Privileges link on the right. I can see how getting 3 at once could cause you to worry about it being 'noisy'.